# why am I not able to compare a space in string after splitting to a space?

Tags: python, comparison

```py
def str_to_list(str):
    # Insert your code here
    new = list(str)
    for i in new:
        if i ==  or (i.isdigit() and int(i) > 5):
            new.remove(i)
    return new
```

I expect out to be `['d', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'a', 'r']`

But I get `[' ', 'd', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'a', 'r']`

Comment: calling function with :-

Comment: print(str_to_list("6 dollar"))

Comment: sure j1-lee...will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose there was a typo
`if i ==  or (i.isdigit() and int(i) > 5)`
As this should result into a syntax error.

So I guess it was meant to be?
`if i == " " or (i.isdigit() and int(i) > 5)`

In that case, I would suspect that it is due to indices in your array  getting shifted while you were iterating over it and at the same time removing elements from it.
It is generally not recommended to modify a list in such a way that indices shift, while iterating over it.
Like in this example, where you are trying to remove spaces and specific numbers. And it would mean that after removing the "5" from array, you are ended up with two " " str spaces in your array. But iterator is not going to reset it's counter. It only does a number of iterators that was determined at the very start of the process. So there are not resets to previous positions. But at the same time we are being left with a our " " " str which ended up there after  "6" was removed. It basically shifted it position to the one that "6" had before. While spefici checks were perfmored at the position from which " " had moved away.
Tried my best to explain it. But yeah, there is a reason why it is considered a bad practice. It really makes things difficult to follow. Well it does for me for sure.
Instead I would suggest something like this:

```
def str_to_list(x):
    formatted = [i for i in [s for s in list(x) 
                    if not(s.isdigit() and int(s) > 5)]
                    if not i.ispace()]]
    return formatted
```

or less concise, but easier to follow:

```
def str_to_list(x):
    new_lst = []
    for i in list(x):
        if i.isspace():
            pass
        elif (i.isdigit() and int(i) > 5):
            pass
        else:
            new_lst.append(i)
    return new_lst
```

It is a much more safer option and makes the whole thing less complicated in general if instead there is new array prepared while iterating over the original one.

I hope it helped.

Comment: Many thanks...I think I got an understanding of this behaviour....

Comment: Just in case I have updated the answer with a small edit, pointing  at which step  specifically it skips the test for that whitespace. 
Hopefully it made things a bit more clear.

Comment: Thanks @Crassius for making it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

try to write this code like

```
if i == " " or (i.is digit() and int(i)>5)
```

Like this the space will evaluate like a string

Comment: Thanks for responding...but I had tried this out too...no help

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` with `list`. Also note that you should not use `str` as a variable or a function because it's already a symbol/function in Python, it may cause some weird bugs.

```
def str_to_list(string):
    new = list(string)
    for i in new:
        if i.isdigit() and int(i) > 5:
            new.remove(i)

    # This will remove all whitespaces from your list.
    return list(filter(str.strip, new))

print(str_to_list("6 dollars"))
# Output: ['d', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'a', 'r', 's']
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: yea...this helped..thanks a lot....but I still have a doubt why  i == " " or (i.is digit() and int(i)>5) didnot work out

Comment: @sukant i == " " didn't work because it's not in your list. When you remove the item from the list then it doesn't actually remove it. remove function just replace that element with a white space. If you filter the list after removal of the item it will remove all spaces.

Comment: Thanks for helping @Light-lens...but I am not very sure about "When you remove the item from the list then it doesn't actually remove it. remove function just replace that element with a white space".....The reason is if I run below program:-

n1=['6', ' ','d', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'a', 'r']
n1.remove(" ")
print(n1)

I get output :- ['6', 'd', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'a', 'r']

This is mostly because the element was completely removed using remove function.

Comment: @sukant I said that because if you iterate your list item-by-item then it doesn't catch that white-space, if you type ' i == " " ' in your code then it's actually useless in this sense because remove function doesn't allow you to remove any element during iteration. You can use pop function but if you want to stick with remove just you can you the code I suggested.